# How to get the elements on a scene JavaFX/Add objects to Scene dynamically

Tags: java, javafx, children, scene

I have a scene - I want to pull all of the elements on that scene.

Basically, this is what I'm trying to create: A window with a button at the top that, when clicked, will "spawn" a new block on the screen that is draggable/interactable in other ways. I already have this down with blocks that I add in the code. But I want to make this dynamic, and for that, I need to be able to loop through all the objects on my scene, and I need to know how to add objects dynamically to the scene.

So, to make this clearer - I have two questions.

How do I add a rectangle or a circle or anything for that matter dynamically on the press of a button?
How do I pull a list of all things on the scene. If I add rectangles, I want to be able to do something like scene.getElements() and have it return a list of elements on that scene so I can loop through them and check stuff about them.

My code:

```
final Circle circle = new Circle(200, 150, 50, Color.BLUEVIOLET);
final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.setX(50);
rectangle.setY(50);
rectangle.setWidth(200);
rectangle.setHeight(100);
rectangle.setFill(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
final Circle pizzaCrust = new Circle(SCENE_WIDTH/2, SCENE_HEIGHT/2, SCENE_WIDTH/2-150, Color.TAN);
final Circle pizzaInside = new Circle(SCENE_WIDTH/2, SCENE_HEIGHT/2, SCENE_WIDTH/2-160, Color.LIGHTYELLOW);
final Group group = new Group(pizzaCrust, pizzaInside, rectangle, circle);
final Scene scene = new Scene(group, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [Pane#getChildren](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) method. You can loop in the list, and if you find a Pane, you can recursively call the method again.

Be careful because not JavaFX elements are subclass of Pane.

Note also that getChildren returns an ObservableList, so if you add an element to it, it will be shown on the stage.

Comment: Ok. How about my other question? How do I dynamically add more children to the group after I've already created my scene?

Comment: You can just add it to the list which you acquired by the getChildren method.

Comment: Ok. And that will add it to the scene without me having to update anything else?

Comment: Yes, because JavaFX uses Observable collections. If any modification happens, the collection listener will call the JavaFX to repaint the scene.

Comment: Wonderful. Last question - is there any way to get the groups that are added to the scene? So if I pass a scene along to another method, I could get the group by doing something like scene.getGroups() or something. Or do I HAVE to pass along the group as well?

Comment: The scene uses a tree hierarchy. There is only one root element, in your case 'group'. You can add more groups to this root group and if you want to get the groups you added previously, you can call getChildren on the root group. Then iterate through the list and check if the element is a Group. (node instanceof Group)

Comment: Thanks. So I can call something like scene.getRoot().getChildren(), then loop through and use node instanceOf ____ to get whatever I want?

Comment: Is there any way for me to name the groups if I have multiple groups so that they are easier to differentiate between later when I do getChildren()?

Comment: There is no built-in option for this. But you can create a class which is a subclass of Group and has a String field called name. But when you are iterating over the children elements, make sure you cast it to the newly created type.